# Store two integers in one single byte

Tags: memory, bit

I'd like to store two 4-bit integer (1,4,7.....)  into a single byte.

I have 2 integer `a=0001` and `b=1111`, I like to store this to integer into one single byte in memory.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: FYI a 4 bit integer is colloquially known as a nibble (at least to us old guys)

Answer (score 5):

You need to bit-shift one of them by four bits, then use a binary OR.

```
unsigned char number = (a << 4) | b;
```

And to get them back out, mask one with 1111b, and shift the other back:

```
a = number >> 4;
b = number & 15;
```

Comment: I +1 the answer but I just wanted to point out that the OP didn't provide much info so it's not clear that unsigned short is a byte on the target.

Comment: Good point.  Even though we're guessing what he's using, `char` is probably more generally correct.

Comment: the 15 equals 0xf (= dec: 15 = bin: "1111")